# LINQ query and sub-query enumeration count in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, .net-4.0

suppose I have this query :

```
  int[] Numbers= new int[5]{5,2,3,4,5};

  var query =  from a in Numbers
      where a== Numbers.Max (n => n) //notice MAX  he should also get his value somehow
      select a;

foreach (var element in query)
  Console.WriteLine (element);
```

- How many times does `Numbers` is  **enumerated** when running the `foreach` ?
- how can I test it ( I mean , writing a code which tells me the number of iterations)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be iterated 6 times.  Once for the `Where` and once per element for the `Max`.

The code to demonstrate this:

```
private static int count = 0;
public static IEnumerable<int> Regurgitate(IEnumerable<int> source)
{
    count++;
    Console.WriteLine("Iterated sequence {0} times", count);
    foreach (int i in source)
        yield return i;
}

int[] Numbers = new int[5] { 5, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

IEnumerable<int> sequence = Regurgitate(Numbers);

var query = from a in sequence
            where a == sequence.Max(n => n)
            select a;
```

It will print "Iterated sequence 6 times".

We could make a more general purpose wrapper that is more flexible, if you're planning to use this to experiment with other cases:

```
public class EnumerableWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> source;
    public EnumerableWrapper(IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        this.source = source;
    }

    public int IterationsStarted { get; private set; }
    public int NumMoveNexts { get; private set; }
    public int IterationsFinished { get; private set; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        IterationsStarted++;

        foreach (T item in source)
        {
            NumMoveNexts++;
            yield return item;
        }

        IterationsFinished++;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format(
@"Iterations Started: {0}
Iterations Finished: {1}
Number of move next calls: {2}"
, IterationsStarted, IterationsFinished, NumMoveNexts);

    }
}
```

This has several advantages over the other function:

1. It records both the number of iterations started, the number of iterations that were completed, and the total number of times all of the sequences were incremented.
2. You can create different instances to wrap different underlying sequences, thus allowing you to inspect multiple sequences per program, instead of just one when using a static variable.

Comment: The **key**  here is the count  **OUTSIDE** the `foreach` which yields.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can check the count

```
void Main()
{
    var Numbers= new int[5]{5,2,3,4,5}.Select(n=>
    {
       Console.Write(n);
       return n;
    });

    var query =  from a in Numbers
                 where a== Numbers.Max (n => n)
                 select a;

    foreach (var element in query)
    {
          var v = element;
    }
}
```

Here is output

```
5 5 2 3 4 5 2 5 2 3 4 5 3 5 2 3 4 5 4 5 2 3 4 5 5 5 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: I dont think it is correct. if im enumerating the array one time , with your code it will diaplay as if it was 5 times.

Comment: do you mean foreach(var v in Numbers) will show 5 times? if yes, you are not right

Comment: `var Numbers= new int[5]{5,2,3,4,5}.Select(n=>
 {
    Console.Write(n);
    return n;
 });
 
 var t=Numbers.Max(); // 52345`.....it was scanned just once . but your code shows 5 numbers.

Comment: because it is called for every number, "from a in Numbers" calc max.

Comment: +1 @RoyiNamir But you ask both enumerations and iterations.  I take this as a count of iterations.

Comment: you can add another console out to foreach to see how many times exactly Min calls

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can estimate a quick count of the number of times the collection is enumerated: wrap your collection in a `CountedEnum<T>`, and increment counter on each `yield return`, like this --

```
static int counter = 0;

public static IEnumerable<T> CountedEnum<T>(IEnumerable<T> ee) {
    foreach (var e in ee) {
        counter++;
        yield return e;
    }
}
```

Then change your array declaration to this,

```
var Numbers= CountedEnum(new int[5]{5,2,3,4,5});
```

run your query, and print the `counter`. For your query, the code prints 30 ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/ZCxFbW)), meaning that your collection of five items has been enumerated six times.

Comment: why put the counter inside the enum; why not outside so you don't need to divide the results by the size of the sequence?

Comment: @Servy That's an excellent question: if I do that, incomplete iterations, say, taking the first `N` items, would not be counted correctly: i.e. a partial iteration would be either counted as a complete one, or not at all, depending on the placement of `count++`.

Comment: I suppose that's an issue of requirements; if you take the first item 5 times what would you want it to return, 0,1, 5, etc.  I don't consider this function to be re-usable beyond the scope of this question (the static counter makes it affect all uses of this function, so you can only use it with one function per application anyway).

Comment: @Servy Making this function reusable is a matter of wrapping it in a class with an appropriate interface, which should not be too hard. All I wanted to do was illustrating the idea of how to use a wrapper to measure the number of iterations.

Comment: Yep, I'm just saying that the function, by design, is just answering this one question and isn't being written to support complex situations not mentioned here.

Comment: Since you brought it up, I added a more robust solution to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The number of iteration has to be equal to `query.Count()`.

So to the count of the elements in the result of the first query.

If you're asking about something else, please clarify.

**EDIT**

After clarification:

if you're searching for total count of the iteration in the code provided, there will be `7` iterations (for this concrete case).

```
var query =  from a in Numbers
      where a== Numbers.Max (n => n) //5 iterations to find MAX among 5 elements
      select a;
```

and

```
foreach (var element in query)
  Console.WriteLine (element); //2 iterations over resulting collection(in this question)
```

Comment: There is a doorman at the array entrance. How many times did this doorman allow passing through him.thats my question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: sorry don't understand what  do you mean *exactly*. If you are iterating over collection, you have to iterate as much times as much elements inside that collection, unless there is no some kind of break condition in the loop (which is not a case in this question)

Comment: yea but there are 2 iterators here. 1 for the outer loop and one which finds the max.

Comment: Why are there 2 iterations on the second one? There is just one `foreach` so surely it iterates over it once...

Comment: @Chris the query itself will iterate over the source sequence N+1 times, rather than just once (which is usually bad practice btw).

Comment: @Chris: there are two 5 numbers in collecton, so the query, **in this question**, will return two elements.

Comment: @Servy: I get that it will iterate n+1 times but Tigran seems to be suggesting n+2 by my reading.

Comment: @Tigran: I'm wondering if we understand different things by "How many times does it enumerate over [array]". To me that means that a foreach would read over it once. I'm wondering if you are taking each read from an enumerable as being count++ effectively. Its the only way I can understand your 2 for the last bit. But in this case it seems to be missing that max is calculated many times...

Comment: @Chris: what I mean here is: that I'm not counting the last request to the enumerator, when the *iterator* sees that it has to break it's execution. I don't count that actually like an iteration itself. If, we count that too, we get +2 more result, in this case, as there is one "break iteration" for LINQ and another for loop.

Comment: @Tigran: Ah, ok. I think we have different definitions here is part of what's confusing me. Also though you do seem to be missing that `Max` is calculated once per element so five times in total. Unless there is some clever caching stuff going on that I don't know about but I would have thought that was an undesirable thing to do so doubt it does happen...

Comment: @Chris: Max  have O(n) complexity, as much as I'm aware of. So from this I deduct that it iterates in "single row" over collection.

Comment: @Tigran MY POV : tell me what you think: 1 iteration over the outer query , and each encountering with MAX  , +1. so there are 5 elements which being equate with max so its 5 ( due to max) +1 global overall. (which is 6)

Comment: @RoyiNamir: as I said, it depends if we count that final (let's call it *break iteration*) like a valid iteration. If yes, *imo*, we have here: For Max (5 iterations +1 breaking = 6) and (2 iterations in for + 1 breaking) = 3. So total (counting breaking too), based on  **all code provided**, **imo**, is 9.

Answer (score 1):

> How many times does Numbers is enumerated when running the foreach

Loosely speaking, your code is morally equivalent to:

```
foreach(int a in Numbers)
{
   // 1. I've gotten rid of the unnecessary identity lambda. 
   // 2. Note that Max works by enumerating the entire source.
   var max = Numbers.Max();

   if(a == max)
     Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

So we enumerate the following times:

1. One enumeration of the sequence for the outer loop (`1`).
2. One enumeration of the sequence for each of its members (`Count`).

So in total, we enumerate `Count + 1` times.

You could bring this down to `2` by hoisting the `Max` query outside the loop by introducing a local.

> how can I test it ( I mean , writing a code which tells me the number
>   of iterations)

This wouldn't be easy with a raw array. But you could write your own enumerable implementation (that perhaps wrapped an array) and add some instrumentation to the `GetEnumerator` method. Or if you want to go deeper, go the whole hog and write a custom enumerator with instrumentation on `MoveNext` and `Current` as well.

Comment: Why would you write your own movenext/current methods?  Iterator blocks make that almost completely obsolete.

Comment: For precisely this sort of low-level instrumentation. To understand how LINQ-to-Objects interacts with its data-sources.

Comment: @Ani: I suspect what servy meant is why write those methods rather than just doign what others here have done and putting output into a method that wraps the enum with a yield return. I think the answer is probably that wrapping the calls to movenext and current allow you to see exactly when those are called if you really wanted to know that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Count via public property also yields 6.

```
private static int ncount = 0;
private int[] numbers= new int[5]{5,2,3,4,5};
public int[] Numbers 
{ 
    get
    {
        ncount++;
        Debug.WriteLine("Numbers Get " + ncount.ToString());  
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

This brings the count down to 2.
Makes sense but I would not have thought of it.

```
int nmax = Numbers.Max(n => n);
var query = from a in Numbers
    where a == nmax //notice MAX  he should also get his value somehow
    //where a == Numbers.Max(n => n) //notice MAX  he should also get his value somehow
select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be iterated 6 times. Once for the `Where` and once per element for the `Max`.

Define and initialize a `count` variable outside the foreach loop and increment the count variable as `count++` inside the loop to get the number of times of enumeration.